# Redux form error is undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

Why is error undefined with the validate function? I print the errors in the log but is undefined in the Field. When I try to do field.meta.error I get a undefined. I put that in the inputComponent const after the `<input>`.

```
const inputComponent = function(field) {
  return (
    <div>
      <input { ...field.input } type={field.type} placeholder={field.placeholder} className={field.className} />
    </div>
  );
}

class Test extends Component {

  render() {

    <div>
       <Field name="name" component={inputComponent} type="email" placeholder="Email" />
       <Field name="password" component={inputComponent} type="password" placeholder="Password" />
    </div>

  }


function validate(values) {
  const errors = {};

  if(!values.name) {
    errors.categories = "Name error";
  }

  if(!values.password) {
    errors.categories = "Password error";
  }

  return errors;
}

}

Test = reduxForm({
  form: 'NameForm',
  validate
}, null, null)(Test);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Test);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you return an `errors` object from `validate`, the key containing the error messages for a `Field` must be the same as that field's `name` prop.

So in this case:

```
function validate(values) {
  const errors = {};

  if(!values.name) {
    errors.name = "Name error";
  }

  if(!values.password) {
    errors.password = "Password error";
  }

  return errors;
}
```

For more information, I recommend checking out [this validation example](https://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/syncValidation/) from Redux-Form docs.

Hope this helps!